# symfony2 embed forms manually

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

Some time ago, I came across a way to embed forms which I can't find anymore.

It consisted into embeding the builders, something like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder2 = new BuilderSomething()
    $builder->add('ingredients', 'collection', array(
            'type' => $builder2
                ->add('test')
                ->add('test2')
        ));
}
```

The thing is it was not calling an external fileType, everything was build in one procedure, which I liked for the simple case I am facing (I want to regroup some fields under another one).

Do you have any idea of how to accomplish what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a form called IngredientType, you can embed it in a parent form like this:

```
$builder->add('ingredients', new IngredientType());
```

This is super helpful for portions of forms that may be reused more than once (i.e. contact info fields, which may be identical in several types of forms)

Here's a more thorough example:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html